# span x columns in y multicol environment

Tags: floats, positioning, multicol, baposter

Currently I'm using the `baposter` document class and one of my figures would take exactly 3/4 of the given poster block. So, pretty much, there's a box,

```
\headerbox{options}{
    sketch goes here
}
```

and I want to fit a sketch like this

[image]

into it.

Numbers correspond to the text path. Please note that in both 1, 2, 3 there's might be figures, which I add simple doing `\includegraphics` and 5 is a huge figure (or set of figures going horizontally).

I've tried to do something with `multicols` but didn't find a way to achieve this layout. As well, I've thought about using table for 1-5, but the `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` commands don't work with adjusting the height of the table. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This can be a situation on which the [`xcoffins`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins) package might be handy; in the example below I draw a frame around each coffin just for visual guidedance; I simply put an "a" on each coffin for the example, but you can place any material instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\newlength\Wi% width for 1,2,3,4
\newlength\Wii% width for 5
\newlength\Wiii% width for 6,7
\newlength\Hi% height for 1
\newlength\Hii% height for 6,7
\newlength\Hiii% height for 2,3,4,5
\newlength\gap% separation between coffins

\setlength\gap{4pt}

\setlength\Wi{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-0.75\gap\relax}
\setlength\Wii{\dimexpr\textwidth-\gap-\Wi\relax}
\setlength\Wiii{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\gap\relax}

\setlength\Hi{.2\textheight}
\setlength\Hii{.1\textheight}
\setlength\Hiii{\dimexpr0.5\Hi-0.5\gap\relax}

\begin{document}

\NewCoffin\result
\NewCoffin\aaa
\NewCoffin\bbb
\NewCoffin\ccc
\NewCoffin\ddd
\NewCoffin\eee
\NewCoffin\fff
\NewCoffin\ggg

\SetHorizontalCoffin\result{}

% Fill the coffins in
\SetHorizontalCoffin\aaa{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{\Wi}
  a % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\bbb{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hiii][t]{\Wi}
  a % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\ccc{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hiii][t]{\Wi}
  a % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\ddd{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hiii][t]{\Wi}
  a % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\eee{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hiii][t]{\Wii}
  a % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\fff{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hii][t]{\Wiii}
  a % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\ggg{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hii][t]{\Wiii}
  a % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}}

% put \aaa into \result
\JoinCoffins\result\aaa

% align all other of coffins
\JoinCoffins\result [\aaa-t,\aaa-r] \bbb [t,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\bbb-t,\bbb-r] \ccc [t,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\ccc-t,\ccc-r] \ddd [t,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\aaa-b,\aaa-r] \eee [b,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\aaa-b,\aaa-l] \fff [t,l](0pt,-\gap)
\JoinCoffins\result [\fff-t,\fff-r] \ggg [t,l](\gap,0pt)

% Typeset \result
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\result

\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the third optional argument for the `minipage`s you can control the vertical positioning of material inside the coffins; here's a more realistic example of filling for the coffins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\newlength\Wi% width for 1,2,3,4
\newlength\Wii% width for 5
\newlength\Wiii% width for 6,7
\newlength\Hi% height for 1
\newlength\Hii% height for 6,7
\newlength\Hiii% height for 2,3,4,5
\newlength\gap% separation between coffins

\setlength\gap{4pt}

\setlength\Wi{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-0.75\gap\relax}
\setlength\Wii{\dimexpr\textwidth-\gap-\Wi\relax}
\setlength\Wiii{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-0.5\gap\relax}

\setlength\Hi{.2\textheight}
\setlength\Hii{.1\textheight}
\setlength\Hiii{\dimexpr0.5\Hi-0.5\gap\relax}

\begin{document}

\NewCoffin\result
\NewCoffin\aaa
\NewCoffin\bbb
\NewCoffin\ccc
\NewCoffin\ddd
\NewCoffin\eee
\NewCoffin\fff
\NewCoffin\ggg

\SetHorizontalCoffin\result{}

% Fill the coffins in
\SetHorizontalCoffin\aaa{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{\Wi}
  Some text here in the first coffin, just to illustrate a real example. Let's add some more text so we can see the real scenario.
  \end{minipage}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\bbb{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\Hiii][c]{\Wi}
  \centering
  Here we have a centered text.
  \end{minipage}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\ccc{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\Hiii][c]{\Wi}
  \centering
  Here we have a centered text.
  \end{minipage}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\ddd{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\Hiii][c]{\Wi}
  \centering
  Here we have a centered text.
  \end{minipage}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\eee{\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][\Hiii][c]{\Wii}
  \hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}\hfill
  \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-b}\hfill
  \includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-c}\hfill\null
  \end{minipage}}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\fff{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hii][t]{\Wiii}
  Some text here in this coffin, it's vertically aligned at the top of the coffin.
  \end{minipage}}
\SetHorizontalCoffin\ggg{%
  \begin{minipage}[b][\Hii][b]{\Wiii}
  Some text here in this coffin, it's vertically aligned at the bottom of the coffin.
  \end{minipage}}

% put \aaa into \result
\JoinCoffins\result\aaa

% align all other of coffins
\JoinCoffins\result [\aaa-t,\aaa-r] \bbb [t,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\bbb-t,\bbb-r] \ccc [t,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\ccc-t,\ccc-r] \ddd [t,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\aaa-b,\aaa-r] \eee [b,l](\gap,0pt)
\JoinCoffins\result [\aaa-b,\aaa-l] \fff [t,l](0pt,-\gap)
\JoinCoffins\result [\fff-t,\fff-r] \ggg [t,l](\gap,0pt)

% Typeset \result
\noindent\TypesetCoffin\result

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A way to think of such layouts, if you are familiar with html, is to use boxes the way `divs` are placed in html, but using minipages.

[image]

Here is the MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\lorem{This is some text}
\newlength\Wi% width for 1,2,3,4
\newlength\Hi% height for 1
\newlength\gap% separation between boxes
\setlength\gap{4pt}
\setlength\Wi{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-0.75\gap\relax}
\setlength\Hi{.2\textheight}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt
\fboxrule0pt

\newcommand\area[1]{
\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[b][2\Hi][t]{\Wi}%
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{#1}  % put contents here
      Some text.
  \end{minipage}}%
}
\area{one}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[b][2\Hi][t]{3\Wi+2\gap}
\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{\Wi}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{three}\par
    \lorem
  \end{minipage}}
\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{\Wi}
      \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{two} % put contents here
  \end{minipage}}
\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{\Wi}
       \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{three}
  \end{minipage}}
\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{3\Wi+2\gap}
       \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{four}
     \lorem
  \end{minipage}}
\end{minipage}}
\par
\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{2\Wi+1\gap}
     \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{five}
     Figure overflows
  \end{minipage}}%
\frame{%
  \begin{minipage}[t][\Hi][t]{2\Wi+1\gap}
    \centering
      \includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth]{six}
      Figure overflows
  \end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

The macro `area` is to illustrate that you may need to abstract the boxes a bit to simplify capturing, if you have a lot of layouts such as this. They get to become a bit unreadable. I consider Gonzalo's solution using `xcoffins` as more flexible that what is outlined here, but you need to get to understand `xcoffins` well. Another approach is to use tikz and I am sure someone will post a solution as well. The bottom images don't fit the boxes well and will overflow. I included them to illustrate that the aspect ratios of your images must be proportional to the box aspect ratios.

I have used both `fbox` and `\frame`. Personally I prefer `\fbox` throughout as it is easier to switch the `padding` and `frame` off. During development you need to see the frames, but in the final layout you may want to hide them. The Code with this adjustments can be found at [Github](https://github.com/yannisl/MWE/blob/master/graphics/page-areas.tex).

[image]