# Span 2 columns in 4 columns document

Tags: multicol

I'm using multicol enviroment with a0paper class. My text is in 4 columns and I want to span two central columns in order to place a wide block like on the following picture:

[image]

How I can do that with multicol environment?

PS. I need a simple solution, since I don't need such complicated layout like in the similar [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131972/span-x-columns-in-y-multicol-environment)

Comment: Maybe you can use instructions described in [this file](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/multiple-span.txt) with `wrapfig.sty`.

Comment: Perhaps `flowframe` is the right package for this

Comment: Since none of these columns flow into each other, you could do the whole thing using tikz and minipages.